# Can I infinitely differentiate a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let us take an equation
$$y=ax^2+2$$

**A differential equation is one which can express a dependent variable and its derivatives in terms of an independent variable.**

By using this argument, can I not differentiate the above equation infinitely and still define it as  the differential equation of the above equation? If so then wouldn't it be incorrect because if I differentiate this equation, say 10 times,  and integrate then I will get the  differential equation having order of 10 instead  of 1 and original equation as a polynomial equation of degree 10 instead of 2.

In the text it is given that the differential equation is
$$x(dy/dx)- 2y=0$$

Can someone explain what is the bounding condition here which forces us to differentiate the equation only a finite number of times?

Comment: If $y=ax^2+2$ then what is $\frac{d^3 y}{dx^3}$ and further I do not see how that ODE is satisfied by the $y$ above, more like $xy'-2y=4$

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add 4 there and also $(d^3y)/(dx)^3=0$

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate indefinitely but every time you differentiate, you create extra solutions. Starting with $y=ax^2+2$,
$y'=2ax$. You can convert it into $xy'-2y=-4$. This differential equation has a family of solutions in the form $y=Cx^2+2$.  Differentiating further, we get $y''=2a$, $y'''=0$. Any quadratic will satisfy the last equation.

Comment: Then does that mean i can create any order of differential equation for a curve but after integration i will get a general curve which my original function would be particular solution of?what i mean here is that if i differentiate a second degree polynomial 3 times and integrate then i would get a polynomial of third degree instead of two and my original second degree polynomial will a particular solution of this third order polynomial. Have i understood correctly?

Answer (score 0):

One parameter in the solution means it woyld satisfy only first order ODE.\So
$y=ax^2+2 \implies (y-2)/x^2=a.$ Differentiating w. r. t. $x$, we get
$$\frac{x^2y'-2x(y-2)}{x^2}=0 \implies x^2y'-2xy+4x=0.$$